# How to navigate to a webpage in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

I create a force.com Site using visualforce page. Within the VF Page is a lwc that uses a  to create new record and I want to navigate to a thank you page after record is created. I used extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) to navigate to a webpage but when I run it the  does not show. Is there a way to navigate to a webpage in LWC?

Here is my js controller

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc'; 

import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class AccountViewLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
     
    handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log('onsubmit event recordEditForm'+ event.detail.fields);
        this.navigateToWebPage();
    }

    navigateToWebPage() {
        // Navigate to a URL
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                url: 'http://google.com'
            }
        },
        true // Replaces the current page in your browser history with the URL
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the `{ }` button or triple backticks for multiline syntax highlight. Single backtick is for inline comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Navigation mixin is not supported in lightning out for Visualforce or inside any other containers.

> The lightning/navigation service is supported only in Lightning
> Experience, Lightning communities, and the Salesforce app. It isn’t
> supported in other containers, such as Lightning Components for
> Visualforce, or Lightning Out. This is true even if you access these
> containers inside Lightning Experience or the Salesforce app. The
> playground doesn’t support the lightning/navigation service.

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate)

You need to use the standard JS API,

```
window.open("http://google.com");
```

or

```
window.location.assign("http://google.com");
```

Comment: Or window.location, etc.